# Should I use AVX intrinsics or avoid them if possible?

Tags: simd

I am working on a C++ game engine (target: Windows PCs). I have a CPU bottleneck that could use AVX to speed things up. It is not a must, but I also don't want to miss out on the opportunity, if AVX can really help to make my engine run faster. However, I see that not many games use it, even though sometimes the AVX requirement is "patched out" of the game, which tells me there might still be a significantly sized player base with old but fast processors. So I am in a dilemma: should I use AVX in my code or not?

I found the [list of AVX-supported processors on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions).

It seems every Intel/AMD processor supporting AVX was manufactured in the past 10 or so years. However, I got a little lost among the many versions of processors. There might be some newer chips that don't support it. I am wondering if I would lose out on a significant number of players if I made my game with AVX intrinsics.

Comment: Have you checked out the latest [Steam Hardware Survey](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey)? At a glance it looks like AVX is supported on 95% of devices Steam surveyed. But it's still up to you to decide whether your target audience is similar to their survey base, or what percentage is "enough" for your goals.

Comment: @DMGregory Wow thank you! Of course I checked, but I could not find anything about AVX, and now that you said it, I looked again and I found the info in the "Other Settings" category. I missed it earlier. That's great help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to support CPUs without AVX, unless your game wouldn't be playable on CPUs that don't have it.

If you decide that you do need it, then I'd suggest making it extra clear in the minimum spec requirements, and via an error message when the game is started on a CPU that doesn't have AVX support.

If you look at the [Steam Hardware Survey](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/Steam-Hardware-Software-Survey-Welcome-to-Steam) (under "Other Settings"), you'll see that around 95% of Steam users currently have a CPU that supports AVX instructions. That means that requiring a CPU that supports AVX will prevent 5% of Steam users from being able to run your game (and some of those users will buy the game, and then complain that it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Why not both?

Find out the capabilities of the users CPU at runtime and depending on whether or not it supports AVX, run your new AVX code or the legacy code you already have.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought of this, but as you know it can be a lot of work to do both, that is why I am asking this question so that maybe I don't have to do both.

Comment: It's probably not that much extra work to do both, as it is much much easier to debug non-AVX code so you will want to write that first anyway. I use AVX (and ARM Neon) regularly, and I always first write a code path that uses neither. Another option consider is one of the SSE versions: the registers are only half as wide, but it may get you many of the gains and will get you way above 95% availability.